# Combinations: There are 30 members

Tags: combinatorics

There are $30$ members of the Bay City marching band. Among them, $16$ play the saxophone, $4$ play drums, $8$ play clarinet, and $9$ twirl the baton.

- No one who plays sax twirls.
- Everyone who plays drums plays another instrument.
- Some people that twirl play the clarinet.

If everyone in the band does something, and nobody does more than $2$ things, what is the greatest number of people that can both twirl and play an instrument?

The only thing I can figure out is that the twirlers are only also clarinet players since the drummers all play another instrument (and twirling is not instrumental) and the sax players don't twirl. If you add up the specific numbers they add up to $37$ and there are only $30$ members so.... now I'm stuck.

Comment: The only thing I can figure out is that the twirlers are only also clarinet players since the drummers all play another instrument (and twirling is not instrumental) and the sax players don't twirl. If you add up the specific numbers they add up to 37 and there are only 30 members so.... now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If there are $30$ members and the numbers add to $37$, exactly $7$ people do two things. $4$ of those are drummers who don't twirl.  That leaves three to twirl and play clarinet.  You can construct a list to show it works
$4$ drummers/saxophonists
$12$ saxophonists only
$3$ baton/clarinet
$6$ baton only
$5$ clarinet only

Comment: Thank you for your help! It seems correct, but I don't know how you knew that 4 of the "extra" 7 were drummers.

Comment: Because every drummer plays another instrument.  They each therefore account for $8$ of the $37$ things done.  Some of the drummers could play clarinet instead of saxophone.  I just wanted an example to show it could work with three twirlers doing something else.

Comment: I see! Thank you. Logic trips me up!